# How can I $_POST information to this page without going to it by submitting a form?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, get

I'm using the following code:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url: 'save_desc.php?scrapbook_name=<?php print(addslashes($scrapbook_name)); ?>,
    success: function(data){
    $("#" + id + "below").html(data);
    }
});
```

How can I change this to sending sensitive information (with "special" characters) by posting it rather than using the $_GET method?

NOTE: I've tried to use `addslashes` but this doesn't have any affect in passing strings with wildcard characters.

Comment: Don't use addslashes, use `json_encode()`. addslashes was intended for database work, not javascript generation.;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `type` parameter to 'POST', or alternatively use jQuery's `post()` function:

```
$.post(
    'save_desc.php',
    { scrapbook_name: <?php print(addslashes($scrapbook_name)) },
    function(data) {
        $("#" + id + "below").html(data);
    }
);
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 1):

On top of the post comment from RoccoC5, you can use the jquery serialize function into a variable then use the variable in the post

```
var PostData = $(myform).serialize();

$.post("myphppage.php",
         PostData,
         function()
         {
             //completion code goes here
         },
         "html")
    .error(alert("error with post"));
```

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/